How I can resolve No module named 'requests' in VS Code?
I've seen this as a very common issue and I've tried all of the solutions thus far.
I am trying to install requests in vscode, running python 3.12. pip3 install requests seems to work, but I still get the error.
I also tried creating a virtual env with -m venv env.
I'm sure I'm missing something subtle and unimpressive, but I have been frustrated for hours trying to resolve this. I'm willing to delete everything, reinstall something other than vscode, watch an hour long video. I just want to mess around with APIs lol.
Can any kind soul point me in the right direction?
Edit: including pip3 show requests response.
Version: 2.32.3
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache-2.0
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages
Requires: certifi, charset-normalizer, idna, urllib3
Required-by: google-api-core, google-cloud-bigquery

syspath:
/Users/**/env', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python312.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/Users/**/env/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages'

code I was trying to run:
import requests

url = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/odds/league/865927/bookmaker/5"

querystring = {"page":"2"}

headers = {
    "x-rapidapi-key": "Sign Up for Key",
    "x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.json())


Please include the actual traceback error and explain how you have VSCode setup and how you're running whatever script you are running.

It sounds like you have two different installations of python on your computer.  pip3 is using one, and vs code is using the other.

Please run this command and include the output in the question pip3 show requests and also run this in vs code and show us the results import sys; print(sys.path)

I added some edits to my post to include additional information. Hopefully it can help narrow things down.

Looks like you've got a version mixup. You've got (at least) two Python versions installed, you installed requests on one Python version, but you're running the other.

Of course I did lol...best way to address this? Delete everything and fresh install?

Anyway you need to choose the right interpreter for VS Code Python extension to pick up. That’s the only way out there.

I think you probably want to change your vs code python interpreter to use 3.13, instead of 3.12 as it is using now.
